# on printing a page don not show select box Only show element of select box

Tags: html, css

I want to print a page which has a select box that I want to only show elements within the select box  (dont even show the select drop down arrow). So when a user prints this page they see all the element within the select box and not just the "Select item" text.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <select> <option selected> Select item </option>
                            <option value="1" > 10 </option>
                            <option value="2"> 20 </option>
                            <option value="3"> 30 </option>
                            <option value="4"> 40 </option>
     </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear, be specific and go through the procedure how to post a question.

Comment: now see  my question......................

Comment: can you explain in details about your requirement? I hope I wrongly understood you I removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have an exact duplicate of your select items in a div and make sure it is hidden. e.g.

```
<div class="printselector" style="display:none">10,20,30,40</div>
```

and then in your print style sheet, make sure this is displayed and you select box is hidden.

So the completed html would look like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<style type="text/css">
    .myselector { display: block}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
     <select class="myselector"> <option selected> Select item </option>
                            <option value="1" > 10 </option>
                            <option value="2"> 20 </option>
                            <option value="3"> 30 </option>
                            <option value="4"> 40 </option>
     </select>
    <div class="printselector" style="display:none">10,20,30,40</div>
</body>
</html>
```

have a seperate print.css file with the following code:

```
.printselector { display:block !important; }
.myselector { display:none !important; }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you the complete answer. I have verified this to work in chrome.